# Avoid recompiling with make after running configure

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compile, make, configure

I have a program (`ffmpeg`) that I am trying to install. This is what I'm currently doing:

1. Run `./configure` with the desired options.
2. Wait a minute or so.
3. Run `make`.
4. Wait 20-25 minutes.
5. Get an error message.
6. Run `make` again for some reason.
7. Wait a minute or so.
8. Get the same error message.
9. Go to step 1, and try again with different options.

**Is there any way, after re-running `./configure`, to force `make` not to recompile successfully-compiled files, as if I hadn't re-run `./configure`? Is there any way to force `make` to ignore the fact that the already-compiled files might change when recompiled?**

In case it's relevant, I don't have root access.

### Version info:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
...
$ uname -a
Linux r500 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Make will only rebuild files it has to (if the makefile has been correctly written).

Comment: Do the "successfully compiled files" exist after running `./configure` or `make`? Or those are deleted?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Good idea! Let me check...

Comment: @Biswapriyo No files seem to have been created or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way, after re-running ./configure, to force make not to recompile successfully-compiled files, as if I hadn't re-run ./configure?

Not really. Re-running the configure script has altered header files which may affect how parts of the application are compiled. `make` has no way of evaluating whether those alterations actually have any effect on the files which were built; it will insist on rebuilding anything that could be affected.

Comment: Is there any way to force `make` to ignore the fact that they might change?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Checking for changed files is the original purpose that `make` was created for.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be avoided. Rerunning configure will regenerate component lists for the libraries  which are a dependency for all individual modules and ultimately the fftool binaries.